# SSRS line wise groupig

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I have very basic query, I want to do some grouping on S.No wise,i.e

`S.No    ProductName       Qty       Price
1       IndoorUnit         1         200
2       outdoorUnit        1         300
3       IndoorUnit         1         400
4       outdoorUnit        1         500
5       IndoorUnit         1         900
6       outdoorUnit        1         300`

Now I want group like that

`S.No    ProductName              Qty       Price
 1       IndoorUnit(completeSet)   1         500
 2       indoorUnit(completeSet)   1         900
 3       indoorUnit(completeSet)   1         1200`

Comment: Where do you want to user group by? In `AOT` or in `X++`? Your example is not ok - specify group by fields and aggregate fields.

Comment: You are grouping by S.No, then what are you grouping on?

Comment: i want to group on first two line ,then 3rd and fourth line..so on.

Comment: It would make sense to use another field for grouping. E.g. if you had a `GroupNo` field, using it for grouping would be a trivial task.